# forward declaration compiler error in a struct in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mingw

This compiles in Visual C++ 2010.

It does not compile und MINGW.

```
struct nextifcondinfo
{
  hash_map <string, nextifcondinfo> next;
  int action; 
};

I get an error message:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
forward declaration of 'struct nextifcondinfo'      C/C++ Problem
```

Can you tell me what switches to use in mingw to solve? Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Could be just a deficiency of a compiler, in which case no switches would help :(

Comment: hash map is an array-like structure where there is one element for one key. key1->element1  and key2->element2 something like that. Generally used for fast(and constant time) accessing to an element

Comment: It's not a deficiency. The struct is still an incomplete type when it is used as a template parameter. It is just by chance that it sometimes works anyway with some compilers.

Comment: @BoPersson, I wouldn't say it's "by chance".  In fact, C++11 is a little more flexible in allowing it http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html  With well-written code, a conforming C++11 compiler is expected to work with it.

Comment: @Aaron - To quote from that link *"the effects are undefined in the following cases: (...) In particular - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component”*. I don't think it is specifically allowed for `hash_map`.

Comment: Thanks, @BoPersson.  Is there a list on the internet of the components where it is supposed to work?

Comment: @Aaron - I don't think so. Unfortunately, there are lots of *"unless otherwise specified"* in the C++ standard, and nobody has made a complete list of this, that I am aware of.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe your code is supposed to compile but it does depend on the hash_map implementation. Looks like you've been lucky with VC++ and unlucky with MinGW.

To solve use pointers, for instance

```
struct nextifcondinfo
{
  hash_map <string, nextifcondinfo*> next;
  int action; 
};
```

You could use smart pointers as well.